# How to exactly merge two different DataFrames having completely different columns between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

For example, there are two dataframes namely **df1(n x m1)** and **df2(n x m2)**, having no common columns between them. Then how to merge the dataframes so that output dataframe's shape will be exactly **n x (m1+m2)** ?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_3': [6, 4, 3, 1],
    'col_4': [9, 3, 7, 1], 
    'col_5': [19, 13, 17, 10]})
```

There are lot of solutions posted in this community regarding the following issues, also solutions are available in the web. However, the resources for preserving the above dimensions  **(n x (m1+m2))** are surprisingly hard to find.
For the above example or small size datasamples, below merge method performs perfectly.

```
df1. merge(df2, how='inner', left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

But the merge method doesn't perform appropiately on high dimensional dataframes having huge elements. In the case of kaggle house pricing dataset

> https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

After separating the numerical and categorical features(dataframes), when trying to merge them with keeping row size same, it becomes doubles of the sum of row of two dataframe **(2*(n+n))** for the following merge methods. Is their any other way or appropiate method that works appropiately to fulfill the task?

Comment: Do you want to concat them side by side ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes. Just want to insert all the columns from another dataframe with current one having  no common column between them.

Comment: Have you tried simply `df1.join(df2)`?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: @FelipeFaria It works too. But dimension size decrease 1. I have to figure out why this happens. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are many ways to do this:**

First way:

```
print(df1.join(df2))
```

Second way:

```
print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
```

Third way:

```
print(df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

**Timings:**

```
from timeit import timeit
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_3': [6, 4, 3, 1],
    'col_4': [9, 3, 7, 1], 
    'col_5': [19, 13, 17, 10]})

print('First Solution', timeit(lambda: df1.join(df2), number=10000))
print('Second Solution', timeit(lambda: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1), number=10000))
print('Third Solution', timeit(lambda: df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True), number=10000))
```

The Second solution wins:

```
First Solution 8.202560314644044
Second Solution 7.059892805897661
Third Solution 7.59388310738364
```

Of course, when you don't need the best performance you can also use the first and third ones, I mostly use the first one because it's short.

Comment: Second  and third ones work perfectly. First one doesn't keep dimensions as expected.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat It works for me tho... anyway, remember to accept after the clock

Comment: I think first one should work. But for my case, dimension size(row) is decreased by 1. I must figure out why this works like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no common column I assume you want to concat them side-by-side (axis=1) basis :

```
df1.concat(df2,axis=1)
```

this will concat the two dataframes on column axis.

Comment: But it shows me AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: What is your Pandas Version ?

Comment: Pandas Version 0.24.2